# Ideals containing $(6, x^3-1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to find all ideals containing $(6, x^3-1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and I can only find ten ideals:

- $\mathbb{Z}[x]$
- $(2, x-1),\; (2, x^2+x+1),\; (3, x-1)$
- $(6,x-1),\; (2,x^3-1),\; (6, x^2+1+1),\; (3,(x-1)^2),\; (3,(x-1)^3)$
- $(6,x^3-1)$

However, my teacher said that there should be 16 ideals, can anyone show me other ideals ?
(I think my answer is correct.)

Comment: Where are you getting $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)^3$ from? Are you using any sort of system at all? What are the ideals containing $(6)$? What are the ideals containing $(x^3-1)$? Can you think of a way of putting these together to make $4\times4$ total?

Comment: You're not looking into principal ideals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint.

Given a commutative ring $A$ and an ideal $I$, the ideals $J$ of $A$ that contain $I$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of $A/I$.

So your question amounts to enumerating the ideals of $\mathbf{Z}[x]/(6, x^3 - 1) \approx \mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^3 - 1)$.

We have $\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z} \approx \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ as a ring.

And if $A = A_1 \oplus A_2$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are subrings, then it is possible to prove that $A[x]/(x^3 - 1) = A_1[x]/(x^3 - 1) \oplus A_2[x]/(x^3 - 1)$. Furthermore the ideals of a product of two rings $B_1 \times B_2$ can be analyzed in terms of the ideals of $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Finally, the fact that $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ are fields will be of assistance because the ring of polynomials over a field is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: As an additive group, this ring is $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})^3$, isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^3$, so there are $2^6$ additive subgroups. But many of these cannot be ideals when you consider multiplication by $x$. This could help track down those ideals a little more.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give further hints.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you get that $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-1)\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-1)$ and then this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ and the last ring has more than two ideals, so the OP and his teacher are both wrong!

Comment: @user119003 Are you sure $A[x]/(x^3-1)=A_1[x]/(x^3-1)\oplus A_2[x]/(x^3-1)$ ? Which element in the left-hand side corresponds to $(x-1, (x-1)^2)$ supposing $A=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},\ A_1=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\ A_2=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @booksee I'd say that $(-1,1)+(1,-2)x+(0,1)x^2$ is the corresponding element. (Btw, why don't post this as a separate question? Maybe you'll find more elaborate answers.)

Comment: @user Good idea. I will post it.